# Поместить элемент меню над друг другом

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ПРИМЕР ↑
Нужно разместить "Индия Следующая страна" под друг другом что бы они считались одним элементом относительно левых элементов и были по центру

```css
body {
  width: 1650px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: PT Sans, sans-serif;
  color: #543024;
}

div,
p,
input,
header,
a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1600px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.header a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.055em;
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  padding-left: 36px;
  margin-right: 111px;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.menu a {}

.india {
  display: inline;
}

.nextcountry {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.call {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.call-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 168px;
  padding: 11px 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

.number {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 21px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Morgun Y.A. - DZ3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="logo">
                PhotoTrip
            </a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Главная</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Куда поедем</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">О нас</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
          <a href="#" class="india">Индия
                        <span class="nextcountry">
                            Следущая страна
                        </span></a>
        </ul>
        <div class="call">
          <a href="#" class="call-btn">
                    Заказать звонок
                </a>
          <span class="number">
                    +7 (495) 234-43-65
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="wherego">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="about_us">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="contacts">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/QWGjvwR - обычный flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  width: 1650px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: PT Sans, sans-serif;
  color: #543024;
}

div,
p,
input,
header,
a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1600px;
}

.header {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.header a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.055em;
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  padding-left: 36px;
  margin-right: 111px;
}

ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu li {
  margin-right: 48px;
}

.menu a {}

.india {
  text-align: center;
}

.nextcountry {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  display:block;
}

.call {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.call-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: block;
  width: 168px;
  padding: 11px 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

.number {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 21px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Morgun Y.A. - DZ3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="logo">
                PhotoTrip
            </a>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Главная</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Куда поедем</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">О нас</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Контакты</a>
          </li>
          <a href="#" class="india">Индия
                        <span class="nextcountry">
                            Следущая страна
                        </span></a>
        </ul>
        <div class="call">
          <a href="#" class="call-btn">
                    Заказать звонок
                </a>
          <span class="number">
                    +7 (495) 234-43-65
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="wherego">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="about_us">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="contacts">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">

  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```